# I'd like to pipe a document to and http POST from pdfutils

Tags: http, pdf, stream, fs

So, as you can see below, I'm using the npm module for node called pdfutils. It allows me to split a multi-page pdf into single page documents. I plan to store these documents in a couch database. My main issue here is a huge lack of understanding of the asynchronous nature of javascript. I have been wrestling with this for 3 days and I'm completely stumped.

The author of pdfutils makes mention of substituting `toFile(filePath)` with a pipe or a readstream of some sort, but without an example I'm pretty much stumped. I just don't understand how piping data works in node.js.

My goal is to pipe each of the 3 pdf files that are generated into 3 separate http calls for submission to couchDB. I know how to do the submission, just don't know how to pipe the results and fire off the http event.

`
var pdfutils = require('pdfutils').pdfutils;

```
// This splits one file into separate pages
pdfutils(req.files.file.path, function(err, doc) {

  for ( var i=0 ; i<doc.length; i++) {
    var document = JSON.parse(req.body.document);
    var page = i+1;
    var filePath = 'app/images/'+ document.id + '_' + page + '.pdf';

    // Write the files to disk (but I'd rather pipe to an http call)
    doc[i].asPDF().toFile(filePath);
  }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the stream events

```
var converter = doc[0].asPNG({ maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200}),
    data = new Buffer(0);

converter.on('data', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function( chunk ){
    data = Buffer.concat([ data , chunk ]);
}));

converter.on('end', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(){
   //Send the buffer to AWS or other service
})
```